# Reversing an array, remains in original order

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to reverse an array in typescript. Here's what the original array looks like:

[image]

But when I call `reverse()` on the array, it's unchanged:

[image]

`recommendations` is an array of arrays, declared like so:

```
recommendations: any;
```

And instantiated:

```
me.recommendations = [[]];
```

Can anyone tell me why the array isn't being reversed and how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What does `console.log([1,2,3].reverse())` in the same context say? Never mind, see below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [].reverse() doesn't behave as you expect.
`reverse` changes the value of the array itself, so the array is being reversed, just you're examining both variables `whatever` and `yup` after this has happened.

So the array itself **is** reversed and you've just made 2 references to that object.

Answer (score 7):

The array has been reversed. You've tricked yourself in the debugger.

`reverse` reverses the array in-place *and* returns a reference to the array. In other words,

```
> var x = [1, 2, 3];
> var y = x.reverse();
> x
    [3, 2, 1]
> y
    [3, 2, 1]
> x === y
    true
```